# how to convert an integer string separated by space into an array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string

Suppose I have a string "1 23 40 187 298". This string only contains integers and spaces. How can I convert this string to an integer array, which is [1,23,40,187,298].
this is how I tried

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numbers = "12 1 890 65";
    String temp = new String();
    int[] ary = new int[4];
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0;i<numbers.length();i++)
    {

        if (numbers.charAt(i)!=' ')
            temp+=numbers.charAt(i);
        if (numbers.charAt(i)==' '){
            ary[j]=Integer.parseInt(temp);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, please offer some help. Thank you!

Comment: Use `numbers.split(" ");` first, so you have an array of strings and then you can convert them to int's

Comment: Have a look at this nice tutorial on the extremely useful `split(..)` method: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Comment: `String[]nums = numbers.split(" ")`

Example: numbers = "1 23 40 187 298";
Then nums = {"1", "23", "40", "187", "298"};
Then you can do the following:

`int[] arrayOfIntegers = new int[nums.length];`

`for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      arrayOfIntegers[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are forgetting about

- resetting `temp` to empty string after you parse it to create place for new digits
- that at the end of your string will be no space, so

  ```
  if (numbers.charAt(i) == ' ') {
      ary[j] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
      j++;
  }
  ```

  will not be invoked, which means you need invoke

  ```
  ary[j] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
  ```

  once again after your loop

---

But simpler way would be just using `split(" ")` to create temporary array of tokens and then parse each token to `int` like

```
String numbers = "12 1 890 65";
String[] tokens = numbers.split(" ");
int[] ary = new int[tokens.length];

int i = 0;
for (String token : tokens){
    ary[i++] = Integer.parseInt(token); 
}
```

which can also be shortened with streams added in **Java 8**:

```
String numbers = "12 1 890 65";
int[] array = Stream.of(numbers.split(" "))
                    .mapToInt(token -> Integer.parseInt(token))
                    .toArray();
```

---

Other approach could be using `Scanner` and its `nextInt()` method to return all integers from your input. With assumption that you already know the size of needed array you can simply use

```
String numbers = "12 1 890 65";
int[] ary = new int[4];

int i = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(numbers);
while(sc.hasNextInt()){
    ary[i++] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer for Java 8+ using streams?

Comment: @taurus05 Stream-based solution is already mentioned at the end of current answer: `Stream.of(numbers.split(" ")).mapToInt(token -> Integer.parseInt(token)).toArray()`.

Comment: @taurus05 I moved stream-based solution up right under loop-based solution so people new to it would have better understanding about idea behind it. Hope now it is better visible.

Comment: Or just `mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Yes, and in real world I would probably use your approach, but since this question seems about quite basic issue I am assuming it is intended for Java newbies so I will stay with lambda since IMO it is easier to understand than method-references. Anyway thanks for mentioning about it :)

Answer (score 7):

For java 8+ you can use this way:

```
final Integer[] ints = Arrays.stream(numbers.split(" "))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

or, if you need primitive ints, you can use this:

```
final int[] ints = Arrays.stream(numbers.split(" "))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray();
```

Comment: are you sure this will work with a jdk earlier than 8 ? If my memory didn't fail me , map function and passing functions as arguments are only available in java-8.

Comment: thanks esin88, your answer is elegant but we must consider some OPs who don't have the newest version of something

Comment: yeah, but when i answered there already was an answer for java 7 and earlier :)

Answer (score 0):

Reset the tmp String to "" after you parse the integer unless you wish to continue to append all the numbers of the String together. There are also alternatives as well - for instance splitting the String into an array on the space characeter, and then parsing the numbers individually

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numbers = "12 1 890 65";
    String[] parts = numbers.split(" ");

    int[] ary = new int[4];
    int element1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int element2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int element3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
    int element4 = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);

    ary[0] = element1;
    ary[1] = element2;
    ary[2] = element3;
    ary[3] = element4;

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        System.out.println(ary[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met similar question in android development. I want to convert a long string into two array -String array xtokens and int array ytokens.

```
String result = "201 5 202 8 203 53 204 8";             
String[] tokens = result.split(" ");
String[] xtokens = new String[tokens.length/2 + 1];
int[] ytokens = new int[tokens.length/2 + 1];

for(int i = 0, xplace = 0, yplace = 0; i<tokens.length; i++){
    String temptoken = new String(tokens[i]);
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        xtokens[xplace++] = temptoken;
    }else {
        ytokens[yplace++] = Integer.parseInt(temptoken);
    }
}
```

You can first convert this string into an string array separated by space, then convert it to int array.